# django template not rendering data

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am writing a blog website and for every blog post i made a detail page template but it doesn't render any data it gives me the following error

TypeError at /detail/1
cannot unpack non-iterable int object

**my views.py**

```
def Post(request):
    posts=post.objects.all()
   
    context= {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

```
def detail(request,pk):
    posts=post.objects.all()
   
    context= {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'detail_page.html', context)
```

**my urls.py**

```
path('', views.Post, name='Post'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

**post.html file**

```
<ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
    
    
       
       <li> <a href="{% url 'detail' post.pk  %}">{{post.title}} </a>-
        {{post.author}}<br>
        {{post.body}}
        <br><br>
       </li>  
    
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**my detailpage**

```
{{post.title}}
{{post.author}}
{{post.body}}
```

The error:

```
TypeError at /detail/1
cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

**my post model**

```
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

After rendering it just shows me a blank template.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to retrieve a single object in `detail` view so you should use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of `all()`, like the following:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def detail(request,pk):
    single_post = get_object_or_404(post, pk=pk)
   
    context= {'post':single_post}
    return render(request, 'detail_page.html', context)
```

Then in the detail page access it as:

```html
{post.title}}
{{post.author}}
{{post.body}}
```

> **Note:** Always add `/` at the end of every route, like so:

```py
path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

> **Note:** Django models are written in `PascalCase` so you may change `post` to `Post`.

Comment: i tried this get_object_or_404 and it says "TypeError cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: @shery can you share the full error traceback by editing the question? Also share your `post` model.

Comment: TypeError at /detail/1 cannot unpack non-iterable int object ------------------      my class post(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
 author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
 body = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
 date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

Comment: @shery It is not clear in comments, share it in the question by editing and also it seems error is coming because of some another thing.

Comment: i edtied my question

Comment: @shery It seems that you are trying to iterate a single object, look at the answer correctly it would work and also that is not the full traceback you edited the question with.

Comment: i tried this detail template can render everything else except the data i need

Comment: @shery By looking at the current code you shared, I can't see any problem, maybe problem is somewhere else, you can share the GitHub repo. My [GitHub](https://github.com/sunderamDubey) account.

Comment: my github repo    https://github.com/sheryx0x/django-blog.git